# d3js circle has to blink in the same position without any onclick attribute with provided color

Tags: d3.js

how to draw an animate a circle using d3js . The circle has to blink in the same position without any onclick attribute with provided color
 circle has to blink in the same position without any onclick attribute with provided color

I'm using d3.csv() to parse the csv file. and according to data drawing circles. acorrding on header if columheader META has value =YES
i need that circle to blink
d3.csv("data/loaddata.csv", function(data) {

```
var visual = canvas.selectAll("circle")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("svg:circle")
.transition()
.delay(1)
.duration(1500)

.attr("cx",function(d)
{
var matches =0;
var input =d.source;
var total_len = gene.length; 
for( var i=0; i<total_len; i++)
{
if(gene[i]==input)
{
matches++;
}
}
if(matches==0)
{
xscale =70;
gene.push(d.source);

}
else
{
xscale=xscale+xspace; 
}
return xscale;
})
.attr("cy",function(d)
{

var matches =0;
var input =d.source;

var total_len = geney.length; 
for( var i=0; i<total_len; i++)
{
if(gene[i]==input)
{
matches++;
}
}
if(matches==0){yscale =yscale+xspace;   geney.push(d.source);}return yscale;})
.attr("r",function(d)
{

    var radius =15;
    return radius;
})

.style("fill", 
function(d)
{
var fcolor ="lightgrey";

return fcolor;
}
)
.style("stroke-width","2px") 
.style("stroke", 
function(d)
{
var strokecolor='red';
return strokecolor;
}
)
```

}

Comment: i couldn't find a way to do it.. so searching for the same

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yWw8A/)?

Comment: yes like this but it depends of the data that comes from a csv file. for example if there is source,meta as headers and values are  asd,yes and if meta value is yes than the circle should blink

Comment: Well, I'm sure you can figure it out from here :)

Comment: var cdata=[50,40]; var xscale=40; var yscale=70;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 1600).attr("height", 1600);
var circle =  svg.selectAll("circle").data(cdata).enter().append("circle")
var circleattr =circle.attr("cx",function(d){xscale=xscale+xscale; return xscale;}).attr("cy",function(d){yscale=yscale+xscale+10; return yscale;}).attr("r",function(d){return d;})
function change(){circle.transition().duration(100).delay(100).style("fill", circle.style("fill") == "#ff0000" ? "green" : "red").each("end", change);}change(); Browser hangs and change stops after sometym

Comment: can i know why why the above code hangs in browser?

Comment: If you have multiple circles, don't use the example code I gave. It will, for each circle, select all circles and start transitions on them, causing an exponential increase in transitions (courtesy of the `.each()`). With a setup like this, use `this` to select each circle individually in `.each()`.

Comment: :) thank you.. but couldn't get what you meant sorry

Comment: In the `change()` function, don't use `circle`, but the reference to the current element `this`.